# 45 Degree PCB to PCB Connector

Tags: pcb, connector

I have an application where I have multiple PCBs connected to each other where each board edge is 45 degrees to the mating board. There are plenty of right angle connectors and straight connectors, but has anyone ever used 45 degree connectors? I have very low constraints in the connector, a simple 0.1" pitch 3 pole header is sufficient.

I am essentially looking for a product in between these two P/Ns (as an example): M20-9960345, M20-9990345

Another note is that I am aware that I could manually bend a straight connector to 45 degrees to accomplish this, but this would be for production so I would like an off-the-shelf solution.

Thanks!

Comment: It could be interesting to just contact some manufacturers about this. Who knows, custom connector prices might be lower than you expect.

Comment: Hey, good point. I'll probably try this, the problem is I will be prototyping in smaller quantities so I suspect it may not be cost effective to start. But who knows, I may be surprised.

Comment: I remember there are 15 degree degree dimm connectors, used by a Gigabyte RAM hard drive (to fit 4 dimm memories into a single PCI slot). 45 degree should also be available.

Comment: Sounds like a nightmare design. Are you sure it has to work this way?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

ASIWJ2EDGL-5.08-14P
5.08 mm Pitch Printed Circuit Board (PCB) Terminal Block 45 degree Header, 14 position

Change 14 to 3

Comment: I usually see these with a mating part with screws. Do solder mating exist?

Comment: Interesting option, might be a bit large for my application.

Comment: It needs reinforcement when at an angle otherwise use a smaller header 0.5mm

Comment: This is not a board-to-board connector.

Comment: Phoenix do an [equivalent](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/gb?uri=pxc-oc-itemdetail:pid=1769667&library=gben&tab=1), and do solder mating connectors (e.g. [this](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/gb/?uri=pxc-oc-itemdetail:pid=1943302&library=gben&pcck=P-11-02-11&tab=1&selectedCategory=ALL). Thus it can be used as board-to-board

Comment: For reference: Phoenix [SMSTBA 2,5/ 2-G-5,08 (1767371)](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/phoenix-contact/1767371/277-6634-ND/348842) + [IC 2,5/ 2-G-5,08 (1786404)](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/phoenix-contact/1786404/277-5986-ND/349071)

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard option from header makers such as [Samtec](https://blog.samtec.com/post/bend-done-quick-inexpensive-custom-interconnects/). Here is a screen cap from their site where they explicitly offer what you are asking for:

[image]

I think you can see from the top photo that your requirement should not be very challenging to them.

Answer (score 1):

One semi-jankey solution would be to use oversize through holes or plated slots, so that your headers can be inserted at an angle. If soldered with a jig, it could even be fairly reliable.

Another option would be to use [castellated holes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yT6gD.jpg) on the board edges and solder them together directly.

Comment: I recently needed to design something with three boards offset at varying angles, and this was the optimal solution. Small plastic blocks can be cut or 3D printed to set the offset height and angle.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, certain manufacturers specialize in custom solutions.
If you are willing to meet MOQ numbers the prices should reasonable for such a trivial modification, and they might not charge you for the tooling.

Answer (score 0):

A flex circuit jumper could be used.  These are like a small printed circuit but with kapton or mylar substrate.  A quick look at one online distributor indicates stock lengths are available, but again, you would probably require a custom to obtain the length you need.  There are board mounted connectors that the flex jumpers mate with.